# Does the position of a macro to make a library static matter?

Tags: c++

In my case, I am using GLEW. I'm going to be compiling it as a static library, to do so I need to use:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
```

Does the position of this matter, or can I put it anywhere to the same effect?

Comment: Does the position matter? Yes, it needs to be defined before `#include` any of the GLEW header files. I would defined it in the compiler options.

Comment: @RichardCritten I wasn't aware you could do this, thank you.